# How to Group by user_id and order by desc

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

Hello i am aware this is very basic but right now i am so confused i want to GROUP BY `user_id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 4 (i have posted short example of table and my query)

My table looks like where id is auto increment i only save user_id i only want to take one user_id only once which is lastest entry in database ignore other.

```
Table
---------------------
id     |   user_id  |
---------------------
13     |    25      |
12     |    36      |
11     |    25      |
10     |    42      |
9      |    95      |
8      |    25      |
7      |    95      |
---------------------
so on
```

I have tried this

```
SELECT * FROM  `table` GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 4
```

I want it to output `25,36,42,95` i have also tried many experiments but nothing seems to be working.
Do i need timestamp or something to make it in group? or what query will work?

Comment: What do you get instead? Given your table and your query, I see nothing wrong.

Comment: i get user_id in desc order.

Comment: You want this in one line? Use GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: In the absence of aggregating functions, the use of a GROUP BY clause is inapprpriate. In this case, you probably want an aggregating function.

Comment: If you want result as user_id in this order `25,36,42,95` then try sql query I have posted.

Comment: @Salman A answered very well and it worked great choosing desc limit 100; from million of entry works fine. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are doing a partial `GROUP BY` which does not work the way you expect. Here is a query which produces the desired results:

```sql
SELECT MAX(id) AS MAXID, user_id
FROM `table`
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY MAXID DESC
LIMIT 4
```

The behavior is [explained here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html):

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. [...] You can
>   use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary
>   column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when
>   all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are
>   the same for each group. **The server is free to choose any value from
>   each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are
>   indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group
>   cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the
>   result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not
>   affect which values within each group the server chooses.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT MAX(id) as countid , `user_id` from `table`
GROUP BY `user_id`
ORDER BY countid  DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Who upvotes this? The question has nothing to do with counting!

Answer (score 0):

1. In your example you need to get result like `25,36,42,95`, but sort by ID field. 
   If you will sort by it you will get different result.
2. You get a grouping in your query so you cannot use columns that not chosen in query (id is ommited there)
3. If you still need to order by id, i think that you need to add order by MAX('id') or MIN('id')

---

In your case i`ll make next query:

```
SELECT user_id FROM  `table` GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY MAX(`id`) DESC LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score -1):

In stead of grouping, you can use `distinct`, like below sql query.

```
SELECT distinct(user_id) FROM  `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 4
```

Comment: This should produce the exact same results as the query given by the OP, so this isn't really an answer.

Answer (score -2):

SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 13 id, 25 UserID
UNION ALL 
SELECT 12 id, 36 UserID
UNION ALL 
SELECT 11 id, 25 UserID
UNION ALL 
SELECT 10 id, 42 UserID
UNION ALL 
SELECT 09 id, 95 UserID
UNION ALL 
SELECT 08 id, 25 UserID
UNION ALL 
SELECT 07 id, 95 UserID
) a
GROUP BY userid ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 4

Comment: the OP wants a query against a table, not against an arbitrary set of data that already gives the right answer.

Comment: @siride, that is true. He have to just replace with its table. isn't it?

Comment: wait, something misunderstood by me. I think @adam said is right.