# How to display user data from table by user_id in a where clause, orderby and desc in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause, session-variables

I have checked the replies to this question: [How to Group by user_id and order by desc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296514/how-to-group-by-user-id-and-order-by-desc) but it doesn't clarify things for me.
This is the query i am using to retrieve messages onto an ajax notification area.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY comment_id DESC LIMIT 10";
```

The query above works perfectly.
But i want to sort it by user id for the above query displays all the users messages on one users notification area. I tried the below code for one user and it works.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user_id=30 ORDER BY comment_id DESC LIMIT 10";
```

(Yes there's a user with user_id as 30)

But that doesn't make sense because i want to work with tons of users who will obviously have different session ids. Then i tried this below:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user_id=$_SESSION['user'] ORDER BY comment_id DESC LIMIT 10";
```

I even declared a variable for `$_SESSION['user']` at a time.
Also in the query i have tried the $_SESSION in so many ways i can think of.
like, `. $_SESSION['user'] .` (with the dots)

I know i am doing something wrong, but what I am doing wrong, i do not know.

```
comment_id user_id comment_subject comment_text comment_status
1           30       test            test            0       
2           30       testa           test a          1       
3           20       testb           test b          1
```

0 stands for not read, 1 stands for read under the comment_status column and of course 2 different user ids.

Comment: You want the 10 most recent comments for each user?

Comment: You need to learn how to pass parameters into queries.

Comment: There was an answer some hours ago, but i cannot find it anymore. It was like this `$query = "SELECT * FROM messages GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY comment_id DESC LIMIT 10";` and it worked fine.